# How to create Xml document with 'include' statement

Tags: c#, xml, include

I've managed to write code to make simple XML documents before, but I need to write an XML document that has a XML 'include' attribute.

This is the example I need to duplicate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
   <xi:include href="./file.xml"/>
   <data>
   </data>
</document>
```

There's lots of info on the web about the subject but it seems to be well above me for the most part and mostly concerns the reading and handling of 'include' statements. I only need to write this in to an XML where it will be exactly the same every time.

This is what I tried but it's obviously not supposed to work this way and it wont let me use a blank label.

```
public static void WriteXml()
    {           
        // Create the xml document in memory
        XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();

        // Append deceleration
        XmlDeclaration xmlDec = myXml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        myXml.AppendChild(xmlDec);

        // Append root node
        XmlElement rootNode = myXml.CreateElement("document");
        rootNode.SetAttribute("xmlns:xi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude");            
        myXml.AppendChild(rootNode);

        //  Append includes statement
        XmlElement xiStatement = myXml.CreateElement("");
        xiStatement.SetAttribute("xi:include", "./file.xml");
        rootNode.AppendChild(xiStatement);

        myXml.Save(@"C:\Temp\testxml.xml");
    }
```

Can anyone suggest a simple way to add the includes statement?

**EDIT:**

If I use the following, it's closer to my aim, but adding the href attribute seems to cause the label "xi:include" to automatically change to "include".

```
public static void WriteXml()
    {
        // Create the xml document in memory
        XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();

        // Append deceleration
        XmlDeclaration xmlDec = myXml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        myXml.AppendChild(xmlDec);

        // Append root node
        XmlElement rootNode = myXml.CreateElement("document");
        rootNode.SetAttribute("xmlns:xi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude");
        myXml.AppendChild(rootNode);

        //  Append includes statement
        XmlElement xiStatement = myXml.CreateElement("xi:include");
        xiStatement.SetAttribute("href", "./file.xml");
        rootNode.AppendChild(xiStatement);

        myXml.Save(@"C:\Temp\testxml.xml");
    }
```

Comment: In the above example, it throws an argumentexception: The local name for elements or attributes cannot be null or an empty string.

Comment: i tried moving the attribute text to the element tag and it does not throw an exception but the xml says: <xi:include xmlns:xi="./file.xml" /> instead of <xi:include href="./file.xml"/>

Comment: If add the "./file.xml" as a href attirute, it changes the "xi:include" in the label to "include"

Comment: Code added. I don't know how to use Linq. Just starting out with coding a few months ago, but my boss has thrown me headlong into some small projects (which I'm loving).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as has been noted, your `include` is an *element* and `href` is an *attribute*, so you could create this as follows:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

var declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
doc.AppendChild(declaration);

var root = doc.CreateElement("document");
root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude");
doc.AppendChild(root);

var include = doc.CreateElement("xi", "include", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude");
include.SetAttribute("href", "./file.xml");
root.AppendChild(include);

var data = doc.CreateElement("data");
root.AppendChild(data);
```

But a far easier solution is to use LINQ to XML, which is a much more expressive API.  There are many ways you can use it, one way is:

```
XNamespace include = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude";

var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
    new XElement("document",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xi", include),
        new XElement(include + "include",
            new XAttribute("href", "./file.xml")
            ),
        new XElement("data")
        )            
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. That works perfectly. Now that I see my example as LINQ, I can see how that is a better way to build it. Thankyou.